# Get array images from fire storage and show in image.network

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm getting an array of images from cloud storage as shown in code below

```
final img = await item[index]['pictures'];
List<String> list = new List();
var url;
var ref;
img.forEach((val)async{
    ref =  FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(val);
    url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    list.add(url);
    print(list.length);
    return list;
});
```

and showing the image in alert dialog

```
AlertDialog(
    content: Stack(
        children:[
            ListView.builder (
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (context,index) {
                    return  list.isEmpty ? Text("wait") : 
                                Image.network(list[index]); 
            })
        ]
    ),
),
```

The problem is when the user click to open the alert dialog the images won't show, but I hot reload I can see the images, how can I show the images without hot reload.

PS: I tried using setState() inside img.foreach()

Comment: Could you share how you have tried to use `setState()`? I believe you need to use it in order for this to work.

Comment: Like this '  ref =  FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(val);
                                   url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
                                                setState(() {
                                                  list.add(url);
                                                  print(list.length);
                                                  return list;
                                                });

                                              });

Comment: try doing the `setState()` outside of the `img.forEach()` and let me know if it works. If this does not work, try printing the value of list in the alert dialog to check it's state.